# Get Password expiry date for one single user in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have found this script that filters me the passwprdexpirydate of enabled accounts on AD.

```
 Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties “DisplayName”, “msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed” |
      Select-Object -Property “Displayname”,@{Name=“ExpiryDate”;Expression{[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.“msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}}
```

It works fine but I would like to have it search just one specific AD account that I will type in. How do I accomplish that?

I would

Comment: Your code snippet contains typographic quotation marks; these won't work in all situations - so omit them by using a decent IDE/text editor not a word processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those times where reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) would answer your question, as the examples cover this question...

You can either replace the `Filter` for the `Identity` param:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity USERNAME
```

Or, update the filter:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "USERNAME"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} – 
Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
    Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression= 
    {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Username"}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `pwdLastSet` isn't Password Expiry.